# XCode SVN - Project can't be configured

Tags: svn, xcode5

I checked out my project through XCode. In that project I have a repository externally linked.
But when I click the Source control option in XCode I see the result as follows.

[image]

My project is not configured.

[image]

The externally linked project seems to be configured correctly has the merge option.

I need to merge my project from the branch to my trunk but **Merge from Branch** option is not there for my project.

Could anyone please help how to properly configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I need to checkout only the trunk folder through XCode SVN instead of whole svn (with branches and tags).